# Does object slicing break encapsulation?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

The way I see it, in OOP one role of public interface is to make sure that the object is always in a valid state (that's one important reason why you can't `memcpy` to a non-pod type). E.g. a very basic, pedantic example: (please ignore the java-like set/get):

```
class Restricted {
protected:
  int a;

public:
  Restricted() : a{0} {}

  // always returns a non-negative number
  auto get() const -> int {
    return a;
  }

  auto set(int pa) -> void {
    if (pa < 0) 
      a = 0;
    else
      a = pa;
  }

  auto do_something() {
    // here I code with the assumption that
    // a is not negative
  }
};
```

In this example, class `Restricted` is modeled in such a way that a `Restricted` object always holds a non-negative number. That is how I define a valid state for `Restricted`. By looking at the interface I can say that `Restricted ::get` will always return a non-negative number. There is no way the user can get `Restricted` to hold a negative number.

`a` is made protected to let the option to easily extend the class. So let us extend `Restricted` with a type that allows all numbers:

```
class Extended : public Restricted {
public:
  Extended()  { a = -1; }

  auto set(int pa) -> void {
    a = pa;
  }

  auto do_something() {
    // now a can be negative, so I take that into account
  }
};
```

At a first glance all is ok. `Extended` doesn't modify `Restricted` or it's behavior. `Restricted` is still the same and we just add another type that also allows negative numbers.

Except that our initial assumption for `Restricted` doesn't hold up anymore. The user can easily obtain an `Restricted` object that holds a negative number (an object in an invalid state) because:

`C++` allows object slicing without any warning:

```
Restricted r = Extended{};

// or

Extended e;
e.set(-24);

Restricted r = e;

// and then:

r.do_something(); // oups
```

Something doesn't add up:

- was it wrong to create `Extended` as a subclass of `Restricted`? If so, why?
- was it wrong to set `a` as `protected` if I expect `a` to be always non-negative? Why? `protected` shouldn't allow a change of behavior in my class.
- is it wrong for `C++` to allow object slicing?
- all the above
- something else

Comment: Well, it's up to the class designer. If the base class has a public copy constructor, then I suppose it was meant to be copyable. If it weren't, it'd have a protected copy constructor.

Comment: Or you could declare `a` as an `unsigned int`. You would get a compile-time warning when compiling Extended.

Comment: @KerrekSB Let's say I want it to be copyable. I still don't expect to have an object of base class type that holds a negative number.

Comment: If you want to protect invariant,  make a member private. By making it it protected,  you are saying that invariant can be violated in child classess. The same problem would be seen  without slicing, just with a reference to base class initialized  with a child.

Comment: Nobody has ever claimed that C++ is an easy language. When you derive from a base class, it is up to *you* to make sure the base class invariants are being upheld. One way to do that is to sprinkle `assert`s throughout the code so that at least you can detect when you miss something.

Comment: @Ceros It's not about `<=` The question is sort of like philosophical. What if the condition was `a always >= 10`

Comment: Extended is violating a class invariant of Restricted. It should not be a child class.

Comment: Isn't this the perfect case were you should use encapsulation in a way that `a` is private and the setter is non-overridable and public (or protected). That way the `Extended` class must comply to the type and logic inside `Restricted`

Comment: Why would you make the field `protected`? By doing this *you* broke the encapsulation by consciously agreeing that any derived class can modify it. So what's the point in having a getter/setter method? Just make it `private`, or consider going a step further and make the whole thing immutable (`const`). *"`protected` shouldn't allow a change of behavior in my class"* -- no, that's plainly wrong; **`private`** shouldn't allow it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> was it wrong to set a as protected if I expect a to be always non-negative? Why?

Yes, it is wrong. `Restricted`'s interface *requires* that `a` be non-negative. That is the invariant that the type sets up. And it has no `virtual` functions to permit a derived class to override that invariant.

By violating that invariant (and because of your curious lack of `virtual` functions), `Extended` is breaking a basic rule of OOP: a derived class instance should be able to be treated like an instance of a (public) base class. That doesn't mean slicing; I mean, you should be able to pass an `Extended` to a function that takes a pointer/reference to a `Restricted`, and everything should work as if it were talking to the `Extended`.

> was it wrong to create Extended as a subclass of Restricted? If so, why?

It was wrong to:

1. Make `a` `protected` instead of `private`.
2. Make `Restricted`'s interface non-`virtual`.

> is it wrong for C++ to allow object slicing?

No.

Answer (score 1):

C++ gives you a gun that can simultaneously shoot both of your feet, at the same time. This has always been the case.

If you want to prevent the described situation from happening, delete the base class's copy constructor, and have the derived class's copy constructor take care of copying the base class.

You can also use private inheritance.

It's up to you to pick the best solution to meet your class design requirements.

Comment: This is not even C++ related, you can make a field `protected` in basically any OOP language, which means "any derived class can freely mutate it". And for some reason OP believes that making a field `protected` shouldn't allow it to be changed.

Comment: OP doesn't want to know how to prevent it. In all likelihood, he already does. OP wants to know the philosophical issues with his line of reasoning. Nicol Bolas' answer is much more in the line of the question asked.

Comment: @jaggedSpire ty, you are spot on.